# htaccess rewrite rule another parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rule in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule  ^video_(.*)$ show-video2/?txtkey=$1 [L]
```

Sometimes it can happend that I need another parameter in GET, for example:

```
.../show-video2/?txtkey=122312421&anotherparam=1232
```

The problem is that with this RewriteRule i'm not able too see the second parameter in $_GET:

```
RewriteRule  ^video_(.*)$ show-video2/?txtkey=$1 [L]
```

How I have to modify the RewirteRule in order to see the second parameter ( when there is it )?
Infact if a `var_dump($_GET)` I can only see the txtkey parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your RewriteRule to:

`RewriteRule ^video_(.*)$ show-video2/?txtkey=$1 [L,QSA]`

The `QSA` is what you're after - it means query string append - and will let you capture the rest of your GET